# Is there a way to collapse an if statement to single line? => condition? doStuff();

Tags: dart

I'd like to turn this:

```
  void check() {
    if(condition){
      doSomething();
    }
  }
```

Into this:

```
  void check() => condition? doSomething();
```

Is there a canonical way of doing this?

[Edit]
I'm aware of the ternary approach: `condition? doStuff() : null` but this generates compiler warnings.

[Edit2]
The ternary with `: null` does not generate a warning when used in a single-line expression. So technically this works. I was hoping for something more readable, the dangling `: null`  indicates some weird intent here which might not be a bit confusing to a future reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional operators.

General example:

```dart
result = testCondition ? trueValue : falseValue
```

Specific example:

```dart
void check() => condition ? doSomething() : null;
```

---

Or you could just put the whole if statement on a single line

```dart
=> () {if(condition) doSomething();};
```

Comment: Ya but this generates a compiler warning in dart. Sorry, should have specified.

Comment: @shawnblais  You can disable that warning. It doesn't create issues for compilation.

Comment: In the context of single line expression statements, the latter doesn't compile:
`void check() => if(condition) doSomething();`

Comment: @shawnblais You can if you wrap it in an anonymous function. And as I said before, you can disable the warning for the ternary operator.

Comment: Ya I am aware of both these things, but I'm creating a library in this case, so I really can't ship with something that generates warnings in default setups.

Comment: @shawnblais If you disable the warning in your package it will not go up to a user of it in the future.

Comment: Really just asking if we have the equivalent of a "if" ternary, when a regular ternary is "if/else".
[Edit] Did not know that about warning supressing. Interesting!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219547/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-shawnblais).

Comment: @shawnblais As I said in chat, I do not see the compiler warning you're talking about.

Comment: To clarify, this actually does not generate a warning when used in an expression body =>, only when in block body {}. So technically I guess this is a correct answer. I don't love this readability though but pretty sure it's the best we have: 
`if(condition == null)? doSomething : null`

Answer (score 1):

You are fighting with the Dart formatter here.

You can put anything on a single line, Dart doesn't treat newlines and spaces differently.
So:

```dart
void check() { if (condition) doSomething(); }
```

is valid Dart. The Dart formatter, on the other hand, will insist that it becomes:

```dart
void check() { 
  if (condition) doSomething(); 
}
```

because that's the *canonical* way to format a function with a block body.

Don't fight the formatter. It's not worth it.

You can do awkward rewrites like the mentioned:

```dart
void check() => condition ? doSomething() : null;
```

(at least if `doSomething()` really is an expression).
That will *not* make your code more readable.

There is no way to put a statement in a function body on the same line as the function parameters, the formatting rules will just not allow it. The formatter insists that statements start on their own line (with the one exception being a single statement `else` branch of an `if` statement, if it fits on one line).
A statement block, including a function body, always has a line break after the leading `{`.

There is one other thing you can do, even if it's as ugly as the conditional expression:

```dart
void check() => condition && doSomething() == null;
```

(If you can make `doSomething()` return a boolean, you can drop the `== null`, then it becomes more readable, but still not as readable as a proper `if` statement).

Comment: Ya I agree I don't want to fight with the compiler, I just want the 'If" version of your standard "if/else" ternary, and wasn't sure if such a concept existed.

Usage would be more along the lines of:
`void init() => !_initComplete? _init();`

I agree forcing the ternary into this use case using null is a bad readability tradeoff.